# Setting environment variables in linux using python for ORACLE?

Tags: python, linux, oracle, cx-oracle

I am using cx_oracle library and have to specify the following using linux

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/12.1.0_64bit/product/12.1.0/client_2/lib
export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/12.1.0_64bit/product/12.1.0/client_2

this makes my code work fine

the issue is this doesn't save across every session so I decided to add it to my script instead like this

```
os.environ["ORACLE_HOME"] = /opt/oracle/12.1.0_64bit/product/12.1.0/client_2 
os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"] = /opt/oracle/12.1.0_64bit/product/12.1.0/client_2
```

but its not working. I added that line right after my imports so its the first thing ran, but its not changing the variables.

when I echo those two variables after the script they're still both empty.

Comment: Have you tried surrounding the values with double quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux, you need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH before the process (e.g Python) starts.

Otherwise you can add the env vars to files like ~/.bashrc, or have a wrapper script like p.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/12.1.0_64bit/product/12.1.0/client_2/lib 
export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/12.1.0_64bit/product/12.1.0/client_2
python $@
```

Do you need the full client?  Do you have other Oracle software installed?  If no & no, then consider using [Oracle Instant Client](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html) and using `ldconfig` so you don't need to set environment variables, see the installation instructions at https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html#ic_x64_inst